# React Native Meteor subscription breaks if subdocument added

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, react-native, ddp

**Overview** (Simplified)

I am running a Meteor server with a publication which is parameterised by ID:

```
Meteor.publish('documents.byId', function(documentId) {
  ...
  return Documents.find({documentId});
});
```

The `Documents` collection (name changed) has a SimpleScema attached to it.
The schema for this document contains a field which is an array of subdocuments.

```
Documents.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  subdocuments: {
    label: 'Sub Documents',
    type: [SubDocumentSchema],
    defaultValue: [],
    optional: true
  }
  ...
});

Documents.attachSchema(Documents.schema);
```

I then have a container on the client side in the usual way with a subscription:

```
...
var handle = Meteor.subscribe('documents.byId', documentId);
... 
var document = Meteor.collection('documents').findOne();
...
```

**Problem Description**

On the `react-native-meteor` client, the subscription data is only received properly by the client **if there are no subdocuments in the array**. As soon as a subdocument is added, when I try to re-subscribe from react-native, the list becomes empty. Interestingly if I already subscribed, it still notices changes to the document, but once I reload the app it can't find it any more.

On the server I have checked that the documents are found by logging, but on the client when I do `Meteor.collections('documents).findOne()` it is empty unless the subdocument field is empty.

On the web client for the meteor server, if I subscribe to a document by ID everything is fine, no matter how many subdocuments there are.

***Question***

I suspect this is either some kind of simple typo-style mistake, or an issue with `react-native-meteor` itself. Can anybody else recreate this? I have been stuck on it for a while - my only guess is that maybe the native version isn't happy with the schema somehow?

[Edit] **Versions**

React-Native version: 0.39.2

Meteor version: 1.4.2.3

[Update]

Whilst searching around and stepping through the `react-meteor-native` code to see what it is doing, I found that one time the data actually came back! So this is probably some kind of timing issue?

[Update 2]

If I filter out the subdocument array on the server side, the native client starts working again:

```
return Documents.find({documentId}, {
  fields: {'subdocuments': 0}
}
```

Maybe `react-native-meteor` doesn't like something about the subdoc format/schema...

[Update 3]

I experimentally removed the "id" field from the subdocument array and now everything is working fine. So it is a problem with having a field of type `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` in the subdocument array...

Comment: react-native version?

Comment: Of course! Sorry, it's 0.39.2, and my Meteor version is 1.4.2.3

Comment: your listview is unable to render subdoc?

Comment: The subscription returns the document only if there are no subdocuments. 

If I add a subdocument, the collection on the client side becomes empty.

Comment: subscribe only with documents like this: var handle = Meteor.subscribe('documents', documentId);

Comment: If the component which called subscribe is unmounted, the subscription is automatically canceled.

Comment: My publication is actually called 'documents.byId' (as you will see if you read my question), and the code I have already works on the web client, and also works on the react-native client if the subdocument array is empty. 

I'm not sure what your suggestion is based on? There is no such subscription called 'documents' and hence (as expected) I get an error if I use your code. Try reading my question again carefully.

Comment: Again, nothing to do with unmounted or mounted components. I can log from inside the container method, I see the handle state is not ready, and then it becomes ready. In the case where the subdocument array is empty, then the collection has a document in it, in the case where the subdocument array is not empty, the collection becomes empty.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: are you working on android ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132943/discussion-between-k212-and-codesingh).

Comment: For fun, have you tried commenting out the default value in the subdocuments field in the main scheme? Just as a test.

Comment: Thanks @zim, it's reasonable suggestion and hence I already tried it, but eventually I solved this anyway (see answer I posted). Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I worked out that `react-native-meteor` was misbehaving due to the way I was populating my `_id` field for the subdocument.

Originally, I had been setting the ID to:

```
var _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID();
```

But once I realised this was causing issues, I used the string version instead:

```
var _id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();
```

And now the native client is behaving. I'm not sure if this counts as a workaround or if I was doing something wrong in the first place... the field in my schema has its type set to `type: Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` but it seems to be happy with both the string and the object.